# MVC в Unity? Надо ли? Если да, то как?

Tags: c#, mvc, unity3d

Для начала скажу, что я большой сторонник MVC и вообще не признаю (не вижу?) других вариантов организовать код. Уже имел успешный опыт применения этой идеи в PHP, и мне там это очень понравилось – наверное, в этом причина. Сейчас знакомлюсь с Unity, C# и разработкой игр в общем. Только вот что-то никак не пойму, как применить эту идею в Unity. Я успел хорошенько загуглить про MVC в Unity и понял, что народ не приветствует эту идею (и на то есть свои причины), но, тем не менее, это возможно. Вопрос в том... Что будет контроллерами? Где будет находится модель? Как работать с View? И как всё это связать?

> P.S. Если вы сведущи в данном вопросе и
> считаете по-другому, то я не против,
> если вы меня таки переубедите в
> необходимости MVC при разработке игры
> на Unity, но постарайтесь, пожалуйста,
> объяснить свою точку зрения. :)
>
> P.P.S. Это мой первый вопрос тут. До
> этого частенько тут бывал, находил
> интересующие вопросы и ответы на них.
> Теперь вот решил сам задать. =) Надеюсь,
> примите добролюбиво. :p

Comment: Ну, классической альтернативой MVC является MVP/MVVM (применяется в WPF).

Comment: @VladD Не слыхал про MVP. Теперь хоть вижу, в каком направлении рыть, спасибо. Примерчика (в случае с Unity) не подкинете?) Я был бы просто счастлив. :)

Comment: @JerryGreen: Нет, не смогу, я не большой спец в Unity. По WPF есть много примеров на сайте, наверняка легко гуглятся.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из опыта изучения различных стартер китов могу предположить, что на данный момент разработчики, использующие Unity, вообще очень редко используют какие-либо общепринятые шаблоны программирования. Для себя я вижу причину этому в небольшом времени жизни игры как продукта, плюс специфика самого Unity. Раз, два - и в производство, так сказать.

Если говорить о способе организации пользовательского интерфейса, для себя я решил, что оптимальная модель работы будет нечто аналогичное MVVM, плюс шаблон Команда.

В сцене создаем пользовательский интерфейс, затем объект-менеджер, который будет отвечать за интеграцию интерфейса с логикой. Назовем его, например, `GUIImpl`. Класс должен быть наследником `MonoBehaviour` для того, чтобы мы могли работать с ним в редакторе. В приведенном ниже примере я использую NGUI для самого интерфейса.

Следующим шагом необходимо создать класс-описание графического элемента, например, панели. Я делаю этот класс внутренним по отношению к `GUIImpl`, но это на любителя.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MenuPanel : GUIMenuBase {
    public GameObject SettingsButton;
    public GameObject CancelButton;
    public GameObject ExitButton;   
    public GameObject ResetButton;

    public override void Init() {
        associateButton(NewGameButton, new NewGameCommand(this));
        associateButton(SettingsButton, new SettingsCommand(this));
        associateButton(CancelButton, new CancelCommand(this));
        associateButton(ExitButton, new ExitCommand(this));
    }
    public override void Show() {
        base.Show();
    }
    public override void Hide() {
        base.Hide();
    }
}
```

Как вы можете видеть, класс панели является наследником `GUIMenuBase`. Этот класс специфичен для вашего пользовательского интерфейса. Приведу мою базовую функциональность.

```
[System.Serializable]
public abstract class GUIMenuBase : IGUIMenu {  
    public GameObject Instance; 
    protected Dictionary<GameObject, ICommand> associations = new Dictionary<GameObject, ICommand>();
    protected List<GameObject> activeButtons;

    public GUIMenuBase() {
    }
    public abstract void Init();
    public GameObject GetGOInstance() {
        return Instance;
    }
    public virtual void Show() {
        GUILogic.ShowMenu(this);
    }
    public virtual void Hide() {
        GUILogic.HideMenu(this);
    }
    public virtual bool CanShow(GameObject guiItem) {
        return true;
    }
    public virtual bool IsShown(GameObject guiItem) {
        return true;
    }
    public virtual bool IsAvalibale(GameObject guiItem) {
        return true;
    }
    public virtual bool CanButtonClick(GameObject button) {
        if (!associations.ContainsKey(button))
            return false;

        return associations[button].CanExecute(button);
    }
    public virtual void ButtonClick(GameObject button) {
        if (!associations.ContainsKey(button))
            return;

        if (associations[button].CanExecute(button))        
            associations[button].Execute(button);
    }
    public virtual void OnSourceChanged() {
        foreach(var item in associations) {
            UIButton buttonScript = item.Key.GetComponent<UIButton>();
            if (buttonScript != null) {
                buttonScript.isEnabled = item.Value.CanExecute(item.Key);
                buttonScript.enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void adjustPanelButtons() {
    }
    protected virtual void associateButton(GameObject guiItem, ICommand command) {
        associate(guiItem, command);
        UIEventListener.Get(guiItem).onClick += ButtonClick;
    }
    protected virtual void associate(GameObject guiItem, ICommand command) {
        associations.Add(guiItem, command);
    }
    protected virtual void removeAssociation(GameObject guiItem) {      
        if (associations.ContainsKey(guiItem))
            associations.Remove(guiItem);
    }
}
```

IGUIMenu

```
public interface IGUIMenu {
    void Show();
    void Hide();
    bool CanShow(GameObject guiItem);
    bool IsShown(GameObject guiItem);
    bool IsAvalibale(GameObject guiItem);
    bool CanButtonClick(GameObject button);
    void ButtonClick(GameObject button);
    void OnSourceChanged();
}
```

`IGUIMenu` содержит методы для работы с различными элементами. Я привел интерфейс работы только с кнопками. Далее реализуем действие, по клику на кнопки.

```
public class NewGameCommand : CommandBase {
    public  NewGameCommand(GUIMenuBase aPanel) 
        : base(aPanel) {}   
    public override void Execute(GameObject button) {
        if (!CanExecute (button))
            return;
        DatabaseManagerFactory.GetDefaultDatabaseManager().Reset(); 
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }               
}

public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand {
    protected GUIMenuBase panel;
    public CommandBase(GUIMenuBase aPanel) {
        panel = aPanel;
    }
    public virtual bool CanExecute(GameObject button) {
        return true;
    }
    public virtual void Execute(GameObject button) {
    }               
}

public interface ICommand {     
    void Execute        (GameObject context);
    bool CanExecute     (GameObject context);
}
```

В принципе это все. Остается лишь реализовать класс `GUILogic`, которой содержит логику работы панелей. Затем открываем редактор, находим наш объект для управления пользовательским интерфейсом и назначаем элементы различных панелей соответствующим полям. Таким образом, для каждой панели должен быть свой класс, который содержит все необходимые поля. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на поле `public GameObject Instance;`
 класса `GUIMenuBase`. `Instance` - это объект самой панели. Для большинства операций с панелью нам понадобиться ее корневой элемент.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦ Воу! Ну вы даёте... Я ожидал в лучшем случае лишь поверхностных объяснений в один-два абзаца, а вы мне реальный пример привели :) Чувствую, долго я буду разбираться. Но спасибо :) В PHP как-то оно попроще было :D Кстати, вы, случаем, уроков не даете / ютуб канал не ведете по Unity?) Или хотя бы блог?) Чувствую, многому могли бы научить :)

Comment: @JerryGreen, Буду рад ответить на ваши вопросы по Unity на форуме.

Answer (score 1):

MVC в Юнити однозначно не нужен, как и DI. Он в принципе под это не заточен.
В Юнити нет моделей, контроллеров, вьюшек, точек входа, контекстов... В Юнити есть GameObject, на который добавляются Components. Мы можем обратиться к любому объекту по ссылке на GameObject и получить с него любой компонент через GetComponent<>

С большой натяжкой можно сказать, что View (отображение в сцене) -- это GameObject с компонентами MeshFilter+MeshRenderer, а Controller (поведение) и Model (данные) - это скрипты, отвечающие за его логику. Ну ещё в качестве Model может выступать ScriptableObject (специальный тип ассета для хранения данных).

Более того, в Юнити даже ООП толком не используется, так как вы можете создавать префабы / варианты префабов, и комбинируя на них разные скрипты, меняя их значения в инспекторе, добиваться разного поведения безо всякого наследования и полиморфизма. Наследование тяжело поддерживать, а провести декомпозицию на компоненты, и поменять один компонент на другой -- не проблема.

Умоляю, не используйте бездумно "паттерны" ради архитектурных изысков, потому что потом приходится копаться в чужом проекте и пытаться понять, "что хотел сказать автор". Я попадал на проекты, где пытались применять Zenject, Entitas или MVC, и это был кошмар для разработчика.

Юнити не следует паттернам не потому что "тяп-ляп и в продакшн", как несправедливо заметил кто-то выше, а потому что у него свои собственные удобные инструменты и богатое API, не такое как в веб-разработке или нативной разработке. Потрудитесь их изучить, прежде чем садиться писать код.

Если хотите хороший пример, как правильно организовывать проект в Юнити -- посмотрите, например, замечательный 3D Game Kit. Никаких MVC, никаких инъекций зависимостей, но код чистый, проект легок для понимания, компоненты взаимозаменяемы, и на его основе легко что-то свое собрать.

P.S. Хотел даже на Хабр тиснуть статью на эту тему, но боюсь, закидают фекалиями местные "профи".

Comment: Во-первых, делать всю игру на компонентах и GO - моветон и вообще производительность будет страдать. Во-вторых, даже сами Unity использую DI в ECS 2019 года.

Comment: "Пруфы", что игра только на GO будет медленно работать? Пожалуйста: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

Comment: Читал эту статью, но при чем тут фреймворк DI.
Они пишут: запихни в 1 менеджер ссылки на 10 000 объектов и двигай их, вместо создания 10 000 монобехов. Для этого необязательно всякие сторонние решения внедрять типа Зенжекта.
Потом, часто ли вам приходится обрабатывать 10 000 движущихся объектов? Ситуация скорее гипотетическая.
Во-вторых, моветон - это ваши личные вкусовые предпочтения. Я вот лично считаю моветоном использовать MVC и DI, на мой взгляд, это какой-то привет из нулевых, тупой, сложный и неэффективный способ программирования.
В-третьих, в ECS нет DI, это 2 разных паттерна.

Comment: Классно вы сообщения удаляете :)

Comment: Я нечаянно удалил.
Я писал: "пруфы на то, что производительность будет страдать".
Пруф неубедительный

Comment: Если вы пишите игры аля "работает в 60(30) фпс? а и так сойдет" и совершенно не задумываетесь о вопросах оптимизации под более слабые платформы, то это не значит, что "в Юнити даже ООП толком не используется". На момент первых релизов превью ECS была система DI, остатки от нее можно увидеть здесь: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.1/manual/ecs_project_status.html?q=inject, но она уже устарела, о чем я не знал, т.к. не писал под ECS больше 4х месяцев.

Comment: Ну так они черным по-белому пишут: DON'T Do not use injection. It is deprecated. Даже Юнитеки признали, что эта хрень устаревшая, и отказались от неё. Про ECS я нигде не писал, что она плоха, это вполне перспективная штука для многопоточной обработки и оптимизации вычислений, когда они ее наконец доведут до ума.

Comment: Эм, разница в производительности между 2.8ms и 0.52ms и 0.22ms - "пруф неубедительный"? Самое забавное, что я даже ничего про пользу MVC не говорил, я лишь сказал, что ООП лучше голых компонентов, что должно быть очевидно даже ежу, не то, что грамотному программисту на Unity.

Comment: Да, но вы ради сомнительной оптимизации в 3ms предлагаете отбросить все преимущества, которые предоставляют компоненты и префабы, и нормальный читаемый код превратить в спагетти из инсталлеров, фабрик и инъекций.

Comment: Не в "3ms", а в 5 и 12 раз - это разные вещи. Да и вообще, ведь нарисовать много объектов без каких-либо свойств, кроме позиции и меши с материалом - это ведь такая **редкая** задача, что можно и забить на оптимизацию таких вещей и дальше делать миллиард префабов, ведь разница всего 3ms, да? :)

Comment: Вы точно мои сообщения до конца читаете? Я написал: `но она уже устарела`, не обязательно повторять мои слова в своем сообщении в попытках доказать свою правоту. Если всерьез считаете, что писать серьезный проект на одних только компонентах - верх инженерной мысли, то мне не о чем с вами разговаривать, я даже не уверен, что вы действительно что-то серьезное на юнити написали. Так что пишите что и как хотите, мне, если честно, все равно :)

Comment: Просто у вас корпоративные понты "у нас энтерпрайз, архитектура, паттерны рулят". Дайте угадаю, для нефтегаза визуализацию попиливаете, или для оборонки?

Comment: Лучше понты, чем корявый код ;)

Comment: Вот ещё на Реддите минимум 2 топика, почему НЕ стоит использовать Зенжект. Абсолютно солидарен с авторами.
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/5wq9tk/zenjectdependency_injection_worth_it/
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/brdr3j/dependency_injection_in_unity/
Может, прочитаете и все-таки призадумаетесь

Comment: Я им не пользуюсь, уже который комментарий речь идёт про ооп а юнити, а вы всё про di, мне не интересно "мнение" с реддита - это не "пруф", тем более речь не про di.

Comment: Речь про ООП - окей, ООП в Юнити не понадобится в 99% случаев. Есть хорошее мнение, что геймобджекты и компоненты -- это абстракция более высокого уровня, чем ООП. Как пример, недостаток наследования: ты наследуешь B и C от А, потом D от B, и у D сильно отличается поведение -- приходится лезть в родительские классы и их подстраивать. Компоненты же друг от друга не зависят.

Comment: Или полимоформизм - это когда приводишь типы к базовому, но при этом поведение заимствуется из дочерних. Как подобное сделать в Юнити - создаешь префаб Enemy и от него Prefab Variants: SlowEnemy, RedEnemy (просто изменив скорость или цвет в компоненте). Не надо никаких ни интерфейсов, ни наследования, всё значительно проще.

Comment: `ты наследуешь B и C от А, потом D от B, и у D сильно отличается поведение -- приходится лезть в родительские классы и их подстраивать.`, ну если при любом удобном случае игнорировать принцип LSP, то конечно полиморфизм не будет работать. Если у вас будут летающие и ходящие объекты (и еще 100 вариаций) - будете под каждый дублировать тонны кода и делать отдельные компоненты? А что насчет скорости вызова `Update()`? Статью на эту тему я уже кидал выше.

Comment: Я собственно так и не услышал "пруфа", что ООП не нужно, только "есть мнение". Ну а мне мнение и опыт говорят, что ООП, разумеется не всегда, нужно, в чем смысл спора то тогда?

Answer (score 0):

Сорри за поднятие старой темы, но есть способ проще.

Во-первых, вместо системы событий использовать переменные контроллера.

```
class Controller: MonoBehaviour
{
    Object data;
    Component instance;
    String ctrl_name = "MyController";

    void Awake()
    {
        instance = gameObject.GetComponent(ctrl_name);
    }

    void Load(name, data)
    {
        Component c = gameObject.AddComponent(name);
        c.ctrl = instance;
        c.data = data;
    }
}

class MyController: Controller
{
    MyModel model;
    Object mouse;
    Object key;

    Start()
    {
        model = new MyModel(0,3,150,["model1","mass"]);
        Load("MyView", model.data);
        Load("MyInterface", null);
        Load("MyInput", null);
    }
}

class View: MonoBehaviour
{
    Component ctrl;
    Object data;
}

class MyView: View
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (ctrl.mouse.down)
            DrawModel(data["circle"]);
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, можно копать в сторону NData:

туториал:
http://gcup.ru/forum/59-27429-1